# Visualize or plot Float32MultiArray data field

Tags: ros-kinetic, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar to this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/175151/rqt_plot-plot-2d-data/), is there a way to plot the data field of a `Float32MultiArray` message type? I'm trying to show the FFT of a signal in real-time and I can't seem to find a straightforward method of implementing the visualization I've tried Plot juggler, rqt_plot amd rqt_multiplot and they don't seem to have the functionality

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321890/visualize-or-plot-float32multiarray-data-field/) by [marinePhD](https://answers.ros.org/users/36566/marinephd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-04-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for anyone else who ends up here.....I did a hacky solution to this problem of visualizing uint16 multiarray topics by adding it to the already established `graph_rviz_plugin`.

https://github.com/flynneva/graph_rviz_plugin

it was relatively straight forward, and could be enhanced with the other multi-array types as well IF your use case is similiar to mine where the multi-array was only one dimension, and I wanted to just use the size of the multi-array as the x-axis.

---

Originally posted by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) with karma: 191 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marinePhD](https://answers.ros.org/users/36566/marinephd/) on 2020-11-09**:
This looks quite good actually. I basically ended up converting my data to an image using opencv and then using an image topic to view it in Rviz. I'll see if I can play around with this and let you know how I get on. My use-case is quite similar. x axis is basically each FFT bin while y axis is the amplitude of each  frequency bin

**Comment by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) on 2020-11-10**:
i dont have a float32multiarray topic to test on but I cleaned up my code a bit and tried adding in the other multiarray types. go ahead and try it out and let me know how it goes. https://github.com/flynneva/graph_rviz_plugin/tree/devel

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is due the the `*MultiArray` data types being quite ambiguous. As you have to / can specify the `MultiArrayLayout`, you can put rather arbitrary data in there. The [docs](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayLayout.html) give an example for encoding an image using this data type. So there is no straightforward way to implement a visualization of this.

Also, all the tools you mention actually work on single value data and plot respective time series. Even though you can configure `rqt_multiplot` a little bit more, I don't think you are able to do that with this kind of message easily.

You'd have to create your own specific plotting display, I guess.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-04-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marinePhD](https://answers.ros.org/users/36566/marinephd/) on 2019-04-25**:
This is what I've come across as well. Looks like Ill have to write something it seems. Thanks.